# How do I set the socket timeout in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to set timeout on client.recv in TCP server.

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

last parameter of [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

```
resource fsockopen  (  string $hostname  [,  int $port = -1  [,  int &$errno  [,  string &$errstr  [,  float $timeout = ini_get("default_socket_timeout")  ]]]] )
```